# Include owl carousel to npm project.All way's

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, owl-carousel

For a long time wanted to use **owl-carousel** but can not connect it in any way through `npm` `webpack`.

The official [**site of npm**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/owl.carousel)  wroted

> Add jQuery via the **"webpack.ProvidePlugin"** to your **webpack**
>   configuration:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

//...
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    }),
],
//...
```

I have this config already in my **webpack** config file

> Load the required stylesheet and JS:

```
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel';
```

Try numb **1**

In config like this (*only change css file to scss*) I have following error

**Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined**

Try number **2**

Include also like this doesn't worked.

```
import 'imports?jQuery=jquery!owl.carousel';
```

I got following error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'imports' in 'D:\master\my path '`

Try number **3**

```
import owlCarousel from "owl.carousel";
```

Error like in the first try

My **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');

let conf = {
    entry: {
        index: "./src/index.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
        filename: "[name]bundle.js",
        publicPath: "dist/"
    },
    devServer: {
        overlay:true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                loader:"babel-loader",
            },
            {
                test:/\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: { 
                                url: false,
                                minimize: true,
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }
                      ]
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: "index.html",
            template: "build/index.html",
            hash: true,
            chunks: ["index"]
        }),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': "jquery",
            'jQuery': "jquery",
            'Popper': 'popper.js',
            "Bootstrap": "bootstrap.js"
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = (env, options) => {

    let production = options.mode === "production";

    conf.devtool = production ? false : "eval-sourcemap";

    return conf;
}
```

In my project I have 2 bundle's

**index.js**

```
import $ from "jquery";
import jQuery from "jquery";

import "../styles/main/main.scss";
import "normalize.scss/normalize.scss";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";

 //in here including  owl-config where I config my owl carousel

import * as owlConfig from "./owl-config";

//after this more js code's
```

And second **owl-config.js** all trie's I do in this file

My **dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "normalize.scss": "^0.1.0",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was I don't properly do what  wroted in documentation

```
//...
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    }),
],
//...
```

What was in my **webpack.config.js**

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': "jquery",
            'jQuery': "jquery",
            'Popper': 'popper.js',
            "Bootstrap": "bootstrap.js"
        })
```

How I change it and work's

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': "jquery",
            'jQuery': "jquery",
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'Popper': 'popper.js',
            "Bootstrap": "bootstrap.js"
        })
```